# c-binary "whereis" for Android ICS

Tags: android, binary

I was hopping that by copying the c-binary `whereis` from an Ubuntu 10.4 box to my Android tablet `/system/bin` folder would work, but somehow it doesn't.

It gives me:

> bash: /syste/bin/whereis: cannot execute binary file

I used the program `root explorer` in Android to give permission `rwxr-xr-x` and `suid` to this file, but still not luck.

any suggestion on what to do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile the binary from source that it can run in Android with ARM processors. The binary from Ubuntu will not run on your phone.

Comment: thank you, and how do I compile 'whereis' binary from source, I'm noobie.

Comment: The answer below shows you how to get the source and you need to install make. Now you have to get into detail: There are special build parameters to build an x86 binary or one for x86_64 or ARM. I haven't done this so far, so you have to use your favourite search engine.